# Inserting Row into Sqlite DB(Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-insert

I have table "logs":

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table if not exists logs (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+ "date datetime, city text, " + "type text, log text, nick text);";
```

And method to insert a log:

```
public long insertLog(String city, int type, String log, String nick) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, dateFormat.format(date));
        initialValues.put(KEY_CITY, city);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LOG, log);
        initialValues.put(KEY_NICK, nick);

        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

    }
```

Every time i try to insert a log, i get no exceptions. Method returns every time "1". But when i looked at my table with sqliteviewer i see it empty. What could be reasons for this issue?

Comment: How are you getting access to the app's database with sqliteviewer?

Comment: I am pulling out database from android app folder. I am using android emulator.

Comment: Ok, that should work. Did you do this after you ran the app?

Comment: I found problem, i passed noting to DbAdapter constructor, in which i'm setting database name. I do not know how i do not get any exceptions. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: That is weird, perhaps that created a second database... Glad you found an answer though!

Answer (score 2):

create table Like this way

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table if not exists logs (_id integer primary key autoincrement,date text, city text, type text, log text, nick text);";
```

& insert Like this

```
public long insertLog(String city, int type, String log, String nick) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

         // convert date to string
        String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);

        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE,dateString);
        initialValues.put(KEY_CITY, city);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LOG, log);
        initialValues.put(KEY_NICK, nick);

        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

    }
```

**EDIT:**

call this method

```
         db.open();
         db.insertLog(....);
         db.close();
```

Comment: What does this actually change? You simply removed a few quote marks and created an extra variable, the data looks the same...

Comment: Somehow i find problem, thank you for trying. Problem wasn't here.

Comment: It's was my database name, i was passing to constructor NULL. Strange that i wasn't getting any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

**Complete example** [here](http://www.freakyjolly.com/android-sqlite-how-to-insert-rows-in-database/)

After defining basic configuration in **DataBaseHelper** use **db** object to insert row using below method

```
// method to insert a record in Table
public static String insertEntry(String user_name, String user_phone, String user_email)
{

    try {


        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each column.
        newValues.put("user_name", user_name);
        newValues.put("user_phone", user_phone);
        newValues.put("user_email", user_email);

        // Insert the row into your table
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, newValues);
        toast("User Info Saved! Total Row Count is "+getRowCount());
        db.close();

    }catch(Exception ex) {
    }
    return "ok";
}
```